# Getting the program directory .net

Tags: c#, .net

How I can get the address of an installed application (browser) from .net code. For example, we want to run opera, so we need to get his address exe.

It must return  "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Opera \ opera.exe" for this example. 
Сould you  tell me, about api to obtain the addresses of installed programs on widnows (x32-x64)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Plus, you seem to violate the "[What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)" rule.

Comment: What is an "address of an installed application"?  What does a web browser have to do with it?  What are you trying to achieve?  I understand that there's a language barrier here, but I'm afraid you're going to need to clarify.

Comment: Since when did "What have you tried" become a *rule*? More like good manners, IMHO...

Comment: @code4life actually, that was on june 31st, this year.

Comment: i'm sorry, i try to run application (for example Opera) This means that third-party applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [MSDN social discusion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/b13b4124-c06f-40a8-bd9a-cf4e4ad1fba2) about finding a program that is installed but not yet running.

You can also list all running processes with ID and filename:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
    Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1} File name: {2}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, theprocess.StartInfo.FileName);
}
```

You then just have to identify which is the one you want, and then get the filename with `theprocess.StartInfo.FileName`

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but if Process (for example Opera) not running,how can run it? I can run it if i know his directory or..